# Cannot install libsodium via commandline

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install libsodium using

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

In the install step, I get this error:

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
make[4]: *** [install-nobase_includeHEADERS] Error 64
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Do I need a different verison of some package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing using [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install libsodium
```

Homebrew will deal with all the dependencies for you. You can also review the recipe used by [homebrew's libsodium](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libsodium.rb).